# Why does this LINQ query assign a value of 1 to a NULL value from the database?

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

The `ExamVersion` class has an `int?` property named `SourceSafeVersionNum`

When I execute the following code:

```
var query = from examVersion in db.ExamVersions
            where examVersion.ExamVersionID == ExamVersionID
            select examVersion;

foreach (ExamVersion examVer in query.ToList())
{
    yield return examVer;
}
```

`examVer.SourceSafeVersionNum` is set to `1` even though it is `NULL` in the database.

When I run the SQL code generated by LINQ in SQL Server, the `SourceSafeVersionNum` column value is `NULL` (as I'd expect) but in the foreach loop the `examVer.SourceSafeVersionNum` is `1`.

I can't find anywhere in the code where a default value is assigned or any similar logic.

Any ideas why/where this value is being set to `1`?

Here is the property declaration (generated by a .dbml file)

```
[Column(Storage="_SourceSafeVersionNum", DbType="Int", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public System.Nullable<int> SourceSafeVersionNum
{
    get
    {
        return this._SourceSafeVersionNum;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._SourceSafeVersionNum != value))
        {
            this.OnSourceSafeVersionNumChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._SourceSafeVersionNum = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("SourceSafeVersionNum");
            this.OnSourceSafeVersionNumChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the declaration of `SourceSafeVersionNum` (with the attributes that precede it)?

Comment: Out of interest, why are you *eagerly* forcing the results into a list, but then using yield return? Any reason not to either just return the list, or use return `list.Select(x => x)` to avoid the client being able to modify the list?

Comment: I asked myself the same question. Just inherited this code yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting a breakpoint in the `set{}` method of the property to see what else might be populating its value? You might catch the culprit in the act, then look at the Call Stack to see who it is.

Comment: I am following this line of thinking. I thought it was different enough to warrant a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5489230/when-is-the-value-of-a-property-set-after-a-linq-expression-is-evaluated

Comment: Up vote for the idea. Unfortunately, the Call Stack jumps over the relevant code, only listing [External Code].

Answer (score 0):

As a follow up to this, here is what happened:

The code that retrieved the value from the database was being called twice but through two different code paths. The code path that was assigning the value of 1 was being stepped over by the debugger so I didn't see it.