# When is the value of a property set after a LINQ expression is evaluated?

Tags: sql-server, linq

After Linq executes a query against SQL Server, when are the properties of a object set?

The following property of the ExamVersion class was generated by a LINQ to SQL Classes (.dbml) file.

```
[Column(Storage="_SourceSafeVersionNum", DbType="Int", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
public System.Nullable<int> SourceSafeVersionNum
{
    get
    {
        return this._SourceSafeVersionNum;
    }
    set
    {
        if ((this._SourceSafeVersionNum != value))
        {
            this.OnSourceSafeVersionNumChanging(value);
            this.SendPropertyChanging();
            this._SourceSafeVersionNum = value;
            this.SendPropertyChanged("SourceSafeVersionNum");
            this.OnSourceSafeVersionNumChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

After I execute this LINQ query:

```
var query = from examVersion in db.ExamVersions
    where examVersion.ExamVersionID == ExamVersionID
    select examVersion;

return query.ToList();
```

When/where does LINQ set the SourceSafeVersionNum property?

I've placed a breakpoint on the setter but it is never called during debugging. There is no constructor which sets this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linq to sql classes inherit from a core object and depending on if you're using EF or linq to sql use proxy classes to populate.

Have you tried changing the private property "_SourceSafeVersionNum" to have a get and a set then breakpoint the private underlying variable? The public setters are intended for when your application sets the variable so it can track the change. If it used these when populating from the DB all your properties would fire OnPropertyChanged when they load.

Comment: I changed _SourceSafeVersionNum to a property and it does indeed break when accessing the test backing field. I thought _SourceSafeVersionNum was the backing field, not a property. Why isn't there a getter and setter if it is a property?

Comment: It's a private property which is instance specific. The getters and setters actually provide an entry/return point for those private properties. Nowadays this is hidden from us and when we write public int MyProperty { get; set; } .NET actually manages the private property for us. When you added a get and a set, it would have created a seperate private instance property for the value to be stored in. ie _SourceSafeVersionNum is where the info actually resides for the life of the class in memory.

Comment: Do you have a reference to a description about how .NET manages these private properties? I'd like to know more about them and how they are used in object construction.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SourceSafeVersionNum` is a property of `ExamVersions` it should be set when the query results are evaluated and materialized which happens here:

```
return query.ToList();
```

Of course if the query results in an empty list the property wouldn't be set, since there is no object to set it on.